# Phrase "I am off to ..."

Tags: meaning, phrases

"I am off to Prague". What does it mean? Could you paraphrase it?

Comment: In other words, *"I am leaving for Prague."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"I am off to" is an idiom that means "I'm leaving for" or "I'm going to" somewhere. It can refer to an immediate departure:

> I'm off to work right now

or to an upcoming departure:

> I'm off to Prague {in a few days / next Monday}.

I suppose that it comes from "I'm taking off for [somewhere]" or "I'm going to [somewhere]" or a combination of the two, but that's just my own folk etymology.